# Mysql - Prepared Statement Variable Substitution with Sub Query

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

The following query works fine on MySql version 5.7.25 and returns columns 'a','b','c' and 'days'.
But on version 5.1.73 it still runs but only returns 1 column - 'days'.

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM '
SELECT
  results.*
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ? AS a,
    ? AS b,
    ? AS c,
    DATEDIFF(?, ?) AS days
) AS results
';

SET @a = '2018-09-04';
SET @b = '2018-10-04';
SET @c = 'TESTTESTTEST';
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b, @c, @b, @a;
```

Do anyone know how I can get all the columns returned on version 5.1.73?

UPDATE - Temp Fix until we're able to upgrade:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(?,"") AS a,
    IFNULL(?,"") AS b,
    IFNULL(?,"") AS c,
...
```

seems to work as expected.

Comment: That seems buggy; 5.1.17 introduced some changes to prepared statements (e.g. using the query cache). What version are you on exactly?

Comment: Just to confirm [this is fine in 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81e7122ec871248e381e08857745550e) - doesn't really help anyone here but hey

Comment: Anyway, realistically if this _is_ a bug your only option will be to upgrade but we should be able to find a 5.1 version in which it works...

Comment: Yeah certainly seems like a bug to me. Really need to upgrade!